# Java 8, Base64.Decoder compilation

Tags: java, maven, java-8

I'm trying to compile new Java `Base64` API ([docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html)), because old `BASE64Decoder` is depracated, but i can't understand why i'm getting error.

That's my code:

```
Base64.Decoder b64 = new Base64.getDecoder();
```

I installed latest `Java JDK` version, and maven.

Maven output:

```
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.compiler.CompilationFailureException:      
Compilation failure
pl/kris14an/vinylrepo/ImageDecoder.java:[14,44] cannot find symbol
    symbol:   class getDecoder
    location: class java.util.Base64
```

Apache Maven 3.2.5

Java version: 1.8.0_31, vendor: Oracle Corporation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need new in this line: `Base64.Decoder b64 = new Base64.getDecoder();`

Base64.getDecoder() is static method that returns decoder instance, you don't need to create it with new.

Comment: so true, it is really big inattention.